# Create pyspark dataframe from parquet file

Tags: pyspark, parquet

I am quite new in pyspark and I am still trying to figure out who things work. What I am trying to do is after loading a parquet file in memory using pyarrow Itry to make it to pyspark dataframe. But I am getting an error.

**I should mention that I am not reading directly through pyspark because the file in in s3 which gives me another error about "no filesystem for scheme s3"** 
so I am trying to work around. Below I have a reproducible example.

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

parquet_file=pq.ParquetDataset('s3filepath.parquet',filesystem=s3)

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
spark.createDataFrame(parquet_file)




------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent 
 call last)
<ipython-input-20-0cb2dd287606> in <module>
----> 1 spark.createDataFrame(pandas_dataframe)

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in 
createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
746             rdd, schema = 
self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
747         else:
--> 748             rdd, schema = 
self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
749         jrdd = 
self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
750         jdf = 
self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), 
schema.json())

TypeError: 'ParquetDataset' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local', "retail")
sqlC = SQLContext(sc)
```

This is how you should read parquet files to spark df:

```
df = sqlC.read.parquet('path_to_file_or_dir')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is that the file in in S3 so it thows a different error. t "no filesystem for scheme s3"  So I am trying to read it in a different way.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't read your whole question. I don't know that, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can read data from `S3` via `Spark` as long as you have the `public` and `secret` keys for the `S3 bucket` ... this would be more efficient compared to going though `arrow` via `pandas` and then converting to `spark dataframe` because you would have to parallelize the serial read.

```py
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", ACCESS_KEY)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", SECRET_KEY)

df = spark.read.parquet("s3://path/to/parquet/files")
```

source doc => https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/aws/amazon-s3.html#access-aws-s3-directly

Comment: Thank you for your response. My problem reading directly with Pyspark from S3 in that it throws an error                                                                             
 Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o379.parquet.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3n                                                        even though I tried to set this configuration. Do you know what can cause this?

Comment: might be something wrong with your cluster installation ... what commands are you actually executing?

Comment: from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.context import SparkContext                                                        sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)                                                                                                 sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", )
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey",)
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://path/to/parquet/files")

Comment: I have tries s3 s3n and s3a! S3n and s3 throw the No FileSystem for scheme: error.  when I use s3a it gives this error: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o83.parquet
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found                                      Also I  don't know if it helps but because I am running it on jupyter notebook when I run the above commands it gives this error     WARN FileStreamSink: Error while looking for metadata directory.

Comment: are you putting in your keys?  you have to like this ```sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "whatever your key is")```

Comment: Yes I do that. I deleted them in the comment because of the character limit

Comment: try making a dummy csv file and try reading that ... there might be something wrong with your parquet data or integration overall